# Public properties not accessible in component and showing undefined

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.6

**Blade**

```
<login></login>
```

**app.js code**

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        domain_Name: document.body.querySelector("div[id='Domain_Name']").innerHTML
    }
});
```

**Component Code**

```
<template>
    <div>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['domain_Name'],
        methods: {            
            ValidateUser() {
                debugger;
                //this.domain_Name is null here
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I can confirm that below code holds valid value and not undefined.

```
document.body.querySelector("div[id='Domain_Name']").innerHTML
```

this code was present in many components so trying to shift it in a single centralized place

Comment: Assuming `login` is the component, you need to pass the value: `<login :domain_Name="domain_Name"></login>`.

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass `domain_Name` to the `<login></login>` component.

You do that using props, but wait: HTML attributes are case insensitive.

This means that to `domain_Name` work as it is, you would need to declare like:

```
<login :domain_-name="domain_Name"></login>
```

which is **weird**.

Vue does show suggestions:

> [Vue tip]: Prop "`domain_name`" is passed to component `<login>`, but the declared prop name is "`domain_Name`". Note that **HTML attributes are case-insensitive and camelCased props need to use their kebab-case equivalents** when using in-DOM templates. You should probably use "`domain_-name`" instead of "`domain_Name`".

Although above will work, to achieve a cleaner code, my suggestions are:

- change `:domain_-name="domain_Name"` prop to `:domain-name="domain_Name"`;
- change `props: ['domain_Name']`, `props: ['domainName'],`

And, inside the component, use `this.domainName`.

Demo below.

```js
Vue.component('login', {
  template: '#login-tpl',
  props: ['domainName'],
  methods: {            
    ValidateUser() {
    console.log('domain name:', this.domainName);
    }
  }
});
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    domain_Name: document.body.querySelector("div[id='Domain_Name']").innerHTML
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<template id="login-tpl">
    <div>
      <button @click="ValidateUser">CLICK ME AND CHECK CONSOLE</button>
    </div>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <login :domain-name="domain_Name"></login>
</div>

<div id="Domain_Name">www.example.com</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the data property is being instantiated, assume that the Domain_Name div is not yet populated. Instead, you can set this up on the [mounted lifecycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks).

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        domain_Name: null        
    },
    mounted(){
       this.domain_Name = document.body.querySelector("div[id='Domain_Name']").innerHTML
    }

});
```

Comment: not at present, sorry. if you put the debugger in the mounted hook that I added, is the document.body query still valid / not undefined?

Comment: also, if you have the Vue Dev Tools, you can check to see if `<App>`'s data is defined. https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools

Comment: in the mounted , it shows the value. but when i submit the button in component, it is showing undefined.

Comment: in that case, I think it is possible you are not passing the "domain_Name" prop down to the component correctly, i.e. `<Component-Tag :domain_Name="domain_Name"></Component-Tag>`

Comment: I am using Laravel 5.6.7 with vue.js, I just updated the question and added the blade to show how the component is being used.

Comment: I am not familiar with how to pass props in Laravel, but I imagine it is the same syntax. Worst case scenario, you can access `this.$root.domain_Name` in the `ValidateUser()` method.